Incoming connections
how can I isolate my node from all type of incoming connections and interaction with the bitcoin network?
I need to make heavy querys in my own node and I need all my hardware recources for me. Thanks.
And my timeout is not working...
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=test
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
daemon=1
maxconnections=20
maxuploadtarget=250
txindex=1
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcclienttimeout=1800

# Disable incoming connections
listen=0

UPDATE:
Select privacy and your node will going to not accept incoming connections
https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/#config=eyJuZXR3b3JrIjp7Imxpc3RlbiI6MCwibWF4Y29ubmVjdGlvbnMiOjB9fQ==
